# How to get text pixel size in DataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datagridtextcolumn

I'm trying to find out the pixel size of the text (with the maximum length) in a `DataGridTextColumn` in WPF using the MVVM pattern so that I can set the minimum width of the `DataGridTextColumn`.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Note that unless you use a fixed-width font, AAAA will take up a different amount of room than IIII, even though both are 4 characters. Also note that due to [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) some characters can have a negative space between it and the previous or next character, meaning they overlap. If you're determining the maximum number of characters you can hold, you should probably base that on your widest character.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the text size from font using this method:

```
    SizeF GetSizeOfFont(Font font, string text)
    {
        SizeF size;
        using (var graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(1, 1)))
        {
            var sty = DataGrid;
            size = graphics.MeasureString(text, font);
        }
        return size;
    }
```

Example:

```
    var font = new Font("Segoe UI", 50, GraphicsUnit.Point);
    var size = GetSizeOfFont(font, "Hello World");
    var width = size.Width;
    var heidht = size.Height;
```